# How to get confidence value in Trocr model?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I was fine-tune Trocr model and  i just want to see confidence value each predict or recognition for create threshold or way to created threshold for use with Trocr model .

Way to get confidence value from Trocr model Or custom threshold model .

Answer (score 0):

TrOCR is essentially VisionEncoderDecoder model under the hood with additional preprocessor + tokenizer. When calling `model.generate()` on an image, you need to set *both* `output_scores=True` and `return_dict_in_generate=True` in order to obtain scores:

```
model = VisionEncoderDecoderModel.from_pretrained("microsoft/trocr-base-handwritten").to(device)
...
return_dict = model.generate(pixel_values, output_scores=True, return_dict_in_generate=True)
```

However, TrOCR by default uses greedy search to generate sequences, which does not provide a single score but a sequence of scores. See the [HF docs on GreedySearchEncoderDecoderOutput](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/internal/generation_utils#transformers.generation.GreedySearchEncoderDecoderOutput): In the returned dictionary, 'sequences' is the returned sequence, and 'scores' is essentially the score for each token before softmax. However, I am not entirely sure how to construct an overall score for the whole sequence using these scores.

Instead, you can use beam search instead of greedy search in your model by changing the model config as such:

```
model.config.max_length = 10
model.config.early_stopping = True
model.config.no_repeat_ngram_size = 3
model.config.length_penalty = 2.0
model.config.num_beams = 4
```

Beam search is typically better (though more computationally expensive) than greedy search, and also provides an additional 'sequence_scores' key in the returned dictionary that represents the confidence for the whole sequence. See the [docs for BeamSearchEncoderDecoderOutput](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/internal/generation_utils#transformers.generation.BeamSearchEncoderDecoderOutput) for more info, but I believe this is what you're looking for. These sequence scores look like log-scores, so exponentiating them would give you the probabilities/confidence.

In short, you can get the confidence scores as follows (the config adjustments are from [Niels Rogge's TrOCR fine-tuning tutorial](https://github.com/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/TrOCR/Fine_tune_TrOCR_on_IAM_Handwriting_Database_using_Seq2SeqTrainer.ipynb)):

```
model = VisionEncoderDecoderModel.from_pretrained("microsoft/trocr-base-handwritten")

# set special tokens used for creating the decoder_input_ids from the labels
model.config.decoder_start_token_id = processor.tokenizer.cls_token_id
model.config.pad_token_id = processor.tokenizer.pad_token_id
# make sure vocab size is set correctly
model.config.vocab_size = model.config.decoder.vocab_size

# set beam search parameters
model.config.eos_token_id = processor.tokenizer.sep_token_id
model.config.max_length = 10
model.config.early_stopping = True
model.config.no_repeat_ngram_size = 3
model.config.length_penalty = 2.0
model.config.num_beams = 4

pixel_values = processor(im, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values
return_dict = model.generate(pixel_values, output_scores=True, return_dict_in_generate=True)
ids, scores = return_dict['sequences'], return_dict['sequences_scores']
generated_text = processor.batch_decode(ids, skip_special_tokens=True)[0]
```

I'm fairly new to HuggingFace and VisionEncoderDecoder models as well, so I hope others feel free to improve this answer, but hope this helps.

Comment: Yes , i was do like that but then I config

`model.num_return_sequences = 3`

then the model gave me 3 sequences and each sequence have a score then I gave all score from Trocr model to the Softmax function, so that is way I was done.  may be best I think